# CORS headers not working on Django project

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, iframe

I have an iframe on another site. I can control the code of that iframe, but not the site itself, **and its origin is not my website (it is loaded from another domain)**. In the iframe, several ajax API calls to other websites are made, and a single **GET** request to my own website built on Django. However, this call returns error with code 0. The request isn't even logged in the **network** browser tab (I use Firefox).

Running the same on the Django website works well, so obviously the problem is in cross-origin requests. I added and enabled `django-cors-headers` module, but it still doesn't work. The same error is thrown and nothing really happens.

My Django version is 1.10.5. Module installed via pip for Python3.5. The whole thing works on VPS. Settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'install',
    'account',
    'corsheaders',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = (
    'https://widget.insales.ru',
)
```

Request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://project_url/scripty",
    data: {
      "data": JSON.stringify(r)
    },
    dataType: 'text/plain',
    success: function(data){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
      console.log("Success!");
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
      console.log("Status: " + status + "\nThrown: " + errorThrown);
      console.log(xhr);
    }
  });
```

Not sure what to add, so ask in comments.

Am I doing something wrong or is it about my understanding of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved unexpectedly easily. After a long time I finally tried to make the same request from Chrome and saw that all this time I had been trying to make a call to an unsecure resource from secure. That means iframe is loaded with https and the request is made with http. Activating SSL for the requested site solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening cause of middleware

```
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

Django not allow to use django website as Iframe tag. because django have middleware

```
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

that not allowed to load django site to another website using iframe tag. it check SAMEORIGIN when page loaded. Read full about this topic https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/clickjacking/

You can use decorator for render specific view in iframe

```
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt

  @xframe_options_exempt
  def ok_to_load_in_a_frame(request):
```

Comment: There's a point I forgot  to mention. This iframe's origin is not my website. I can control it, but it is loaded from another domain. I'll edit the question

Comment: So use decorator or remove middleware if you want to show your django website to another domain in iframe tag.

Comment: No, you don't get it. Let's say my site's name is __a.com__. I use a special tool to upload my code to domain __b.com__, and __b.com__ shows it in iframe loaded from __widget.b.com__. So basically I need to make a request from __widget.b.com__ to __a.com__, but I can't. Django has nothing to do with the iframe. And there was no problem in showing it

Comment: Or did I understand what you had tried to tell me? I commented out that middleware, it does not help

Comment: You mean b.com showing in iframe tags in widget.b.com. right?

Comment: Vice versa. __b.com__ contains an iframe tag with data from __widget.b.com__

Comment: Read this https://madskristensen.net/post/iframe-cross-domain-javascript-calls maybe this can solve your problem

Comment: I've read that article before. Well, JSONP is useless as far as I use Python to process the request. The situation with iframe proxying is much more interesting. Code 200 is returned, but I don't get work done (what my server app should do with data). Can't even imagine reasons for that